# MySQL how to select into JSON ARRAY

Tags: mysql, arrays, group-concat

in MySQL 5.7 we have the JSON_ARRAY object. I'd like to perform something similar to a `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field)` but with the results into a JSON_ARRAY.

My current query is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM users;
```

result: john,michael,sofia

I'd like the result to be: ["john","michael","sofia"]

My current solution is:

```
select @j:=json_array_append(@j,'$',name) from users
```

But that's very inefficient since it's re-calculated for every row. Is it possible to achieve that more efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON_ARRAY` to achieve what you want :

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ',')) AS names FROM users;
```

Like this it will let you obtain the desired result without having to re-calculate for each row.